# What would be grok filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, kibana-3

This is the following json sample in which  I want to **filter and index**  on basis of Client Id and User Id which is in Message tag in json.

```
"message": "12 Jul 2016 15:28:14,851 http-bio-9080-exec-3 [INFO ]    corporate_access                                    - Request details - Uri: /corporate/create, Ip: x.x.x.x, User id: 12461, Client id:11048",
```

I want to index the user activity on basis of Client Id and User Id. My filter in logstash conf is :

```
filter {
  grok {

match => {
        "message" => "Uri: %{URIPATHPARAM:url}%{SPACE}Ip: %{IP:ip},%{SPACE}User id: %{WORD:Userid}, Client id:%{WORD:Clientid}"
}

 }
}
```

Comment: Can you post your log line and logstash config with grok filter separately?

Comment: The number of spaces, etc is different in your comment and in your question. Which Log line format is the correct one?

Comment: @MrunalPagnis The comment form might strip multiple spaces. But if you are using `%{SPACE}` in your pattern, it won't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this grok filter:

```
grok {
    match => {
        "message" => [
            "%{MONTHDAY} %{MONTH} %{YEAR} %{TIME} %{GREEDYDATA} \[%{DATA}\]%{SPACE}%{WORD}%{SPACE}- Request details - Uri: %{URIPATH}, Ip: %{IP}, User id: %{NUMBER:user_id}, Client id: %{NUMBER:client_id}"
        ]
    }
}
```

Note: I have removed the `**` around `User id` and `Client id`, since it look like it was just to add emphasis on the interesting parts of the log line. 
But if you really have `**` in your logs, the pattern must be modified with: `\*\*User id:\*\* %{NUMBER:user_id}, \*\*Client id:\*\*%{NUMBER:client_id}`.

Comment: @user2481458 With the grok filter from your question?

Comment: I have no idea why your filter (`filter { grok { match => { "message" => "User id: %{NUMBER:UserId}, Client id:%{NUMBER:ClientId}" } } }`) doesn't work. I tested it (LS 2.2) without problems

Answer (score 0):

This worked !!

```
  filter {
      if [type] == "corporate-access" {
        grok {
          break_on_match => false
          match => { "message" => "Uri: %{URIPATHPARAM:url}%{SPACE}" }
           match => { "message" => "User id: %{WORD:Userid}, Client id:%{WORD:Clientid}" }
           add_tag => "%{Userid}"
           add_tag => "%{Clientid}"
           add_tag => "%{url}"

        }
      }
```